# How to prevent more than one concurrent execution of a controller action?

Tags: c#, .net

The method in question queries and aggregates results from a third party API that can spiral out of control if too many requests are made.

The approach I'm considering registers the controller as a singleton in Autofac and uses a lock to manage the state of a field level variable that tracks if the method is already in progress.

Is this a clean implementation or does it contain bugs/race conditions?

```
public class  ExpensiveController : Controller
{
    private bool _alreadyRunning = false;
    private static readonly object Instancelock = new object();

    [HttpGet("expensiveController/CallThirdPartyApi")]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<MyObject>>  CallThirdPartyApi()
    {
        // Critical Section Start
        lock (Instancelock)
        { 
            if (_alreadyRunning == true)
            {
                return Ok
            }
            else
            {
                _alreadyRunning = true;
            }
        } //Critical Section End
              
        // do work
        var list = DoExpensiveProcessing()
        _alreadyRunning = false;

        return list;
    }
}
```

Here's a cleaned up version of the code that uses a static field to track state instead of messing with the controller's lifecycle. Tested and appears to work.

```
public class ExpensiveController : Controller
    {
        private static bool _alreadyRunning;
        private static readonly object InstanceLock = new object();

        [HttpGet("expensiveController/CallThirdPartyApi")]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<MyObject>>  CallThirdPartyApi()
        {
            lock (InstanceLock)
            {
                
                if (_alreadyRunning)
                {
                    return new ServiceUnavailableResult();
                }
                _alreadyRunning = true;
            }
             

            var list = DoExpensiveProcessing()
                
            
            lock (InstanceLock)
            {
                
                _alreadyRunning = false;
            }
            return list;
            }  
       
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't mess with controllers lifecycle, they shouldn't be singleton for a number of reasons and they are transient by default. You can use a singleton service on your controller though.

Comment: Does CallThirdPartyApi have parameters?

Comment: Why CallThirdPartyApi returns empty result when it is already running?

Comment: If _alreadyRunning was static, you would not need to register the controller as singleton

Comment: Are you using each time the same results? If yes, then you should think about caching - `IMemoryCache`.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler version could be

```
[HttpGet("expensiveController/CallThirdPartyApi")]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<MyObject>>  CallThirdPartyApi()
{
    lock
    {
        //your work
    }
```

Comment: I would like to add that in case the method would be async, lock block cannot be used - you would have to use SemaphoreSlim class for example to do locking mechanism. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 0):

I created a library that could help you achieve your objectives. It's called [AsyncKeyedLock](https://github.com/MarkCiliaVincenti/AsyncKeyedLock) and it's available over NuGet. If you inject a `AsyncKeyedLocker<string>` singleton using DI you would then be able to lock by key, where the key would be the name of the controller. This way you can control how many concurrent calls you want to have to every controller.